# The mice problem

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

[image]

**Problem.** You have $2$ mice, and $9$ bottles, exactly one of which is poisoned. Each mouse can taste any combination of bottles at once, and if it is poisoned it will die after exactly one minute. Once a mouse is dead, it can't taste any more bottles. How many minutes do you need to determine exactly which bottle is poisoned?

This question has me in a complete bind. Anyone who can point me in the right direction as to how to get started with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other assumptions on the tasting process? It seems like you could just have one of the mice taste each bottle in, say, 5 second intervals and then see which bottle it dies exactly one minute after.

Comment: You can shorten the time by having each mouse taste a different bottle at the same time.  So an upper bound would be floor(9/2) = 4 minutes.

Comment: Why do we need $4$ minutes? Why couldn't we get $1+\varepsilon$ minutes by, for instance, having one mouse drink bottle $i$ at second $i$? When the mouse dies at time $k+60$ seconds for some $k$, we'll know which bottle is poisoned (and there's nothing special about $1$ second here).

Comment: @Doug shouldn't it be ceil not floor since after $4$ minutes there will still be one bottle left?

Comment: But if the two mice are alive after testing 8 bottles, you know the last one is poisoned.  So, it is the floor.

Comment: @ConnorGordon, that is a good point.

Comment: Oh I see, had a brainfreeze there

Comment: Please see the **Edit-Images** section in [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @ConnorGordon I'm fairly sure that is the intended answer. As I recall it's one of those trick interview questions that was popular with e.g. Google a while back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you could approach it(fill in the blanks):

In the first minute, give mouse A bottles $1$, $2$, and $3$. Give mouse B $3$, $4$, and $5$.

If both of them die, what does that mean for a bottle of $3$?

If only A dies, give B a bottle of $1$ in the second minute and see what happens.

Likewise, if only B dies give A bottle $4$ and see what happens.

If none die, give B bottles $6$ and $7$ and give A $7$ and $8$ in minute two, proceeding like above.

If none of them die, there is only one bottle remaining.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: This takes max $2$ minutes in total.

Comment: I think this isn't the most efficent solution in terms of minimum number of minutes.

Comment: This takes exactly $2$ minutes @SuzuHirose

Comment: No, it takes $2 \frac19=\frac{19}9$ minutes. One solution (bottle 3) takes one minute, six solutions (bottles 1,2,4,5, 7 and 9) take 2 minutes, and the other two solutions take 3 minutes. Still it seems to be better than mine, so the above comment was wrong.

Comment: Oh no, we get 6 and 8 from the two mice, so that is wrong again. Total time is one minute times one plus two minutes times eight, so less than two minutes.

Comment: @SuzuHirose You are right about my first case. on $6$ and $7$ that means $6$ is the bottle. If A dies then it is $8$, if both die then it is $7$, and if none die it is $9$ no extra testing needed :).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, see my last comment. It works out to an average of $17/9$ minutes, so under 2 minutes.

Comment: @SuzuHirose - Admittedly the problem is not completely clear, but generally it is the maximum time needed to be sure, not the average time, that is intended in these sorts of puzzles. That is, the time that you are guaranteed to get an answer in,

Comment: @PaulSinclair it doesn't make that much difference to the argument whether we discuss the maximum time or the average time since the maximum must be equal to or more than the average

Comment: @SuzuHirose - But for two proposed solutions to a puzzle similar to this, it is possible for one to have a higher average time than the other, but a lower max time. This happens when one tries to gather information evenly about all cases, while the other concentrates on the most likely cases while leaving unlikely cases alone until the likely cases are eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** This answer isn't the best one since it ignores one of the pieces of information, both mice die.)

At step one, mouse 1 tastes 1,2,3 combined; mouse 2 tastes 4,5,6 combined; if both survive mouse 1 tastes bottle 7, mouse 2 bottle 8, with an answer in 2 minutes.

If mouse 1 dies after step one, mouse 2 then tastes bottle 2, then if it survives bottle 3, with an answer in 2 (1 case) or 3 (2 cases) minutes. Similarly, if 2 dies after step one, mouse 1 tastes 4 then 5.

So you need average of $ (2\times 3+2\times 2+3\times 4)/9=2\frac49 $ minutes.

This problem is an information theoretic problem similar to Huffman encoding with an alphabet of four signals, the signals being "mouse 1 dies", "mouse 2 dies", "both mice die", and "nobody dies". The above solution ignored the case of "both mice die".

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those trick interview questions where the idea is to see if you can think quickly enough on your feet to realise the problem is trivial. The key is to realise that you do not have to wait for the results of one test to start another one.

So you give the first dose to a mouse at t=0, the second at t+ε,...,t+7ε and check carefully the time at which it dies. Note that the question specifies that the mouse dies after *exactly* one minute.

So the answer is 'a little over 1 minute, for some definition of a little'.

[Answer as noted in a comment by @ConnorGordon].